# VB.Net) using condition data reader on join tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysqldatareader

I'm trying to collect data from joining table and currently there is a null displaying (no error found). I think my code isn't efficient tough. But here it is what I'm trying:

```
conn.Open()
    sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand("select tabsen.id_absen, tsiswa.NIS, tsiswa.nama, tabsen.alpa, tabsen.izin, tabsen.sakit, tabsen.tahun_ajaran from tabsen join tsiswa on tabsen.NIS = tsiswa.NIS where tsiswa.NIS like '%" & txtnis.Text & "%'", conn)
    dr = sqlcmd.executereader()
    dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows Then

        txtid.Text = dr.Item("id_absen")
        txtnis.Text = dr.Item("NIS")
        txtnama.Text = dr.Item("nama")
        txta.Text = dr.Item("alpa")
        txti.Text = dr.Item("izin")
        txts.Text = dr.Item("sakit")
        cmbtahun.Text = dr.Item("tahun_ajaran")
        txta.Focus()
        btnsave.Text = "UPDATE"
        btndelete.Enabled = True
        txtjumlah.Enabled = True
        cmbpredikat.Enabled = True
        cmbtahun.Enabled = True
        txtnis.Enabled = False
        dr.Close()

    Else
        While dr.Read()
            txtnama.Text = dr("nama")
        End While
        dr.Close()
        MsgBox("data absensi belum diisi")
    End If
    conn.Close()
```

If row found, it works like a charm. But when its empty on table 'tabsen', there is no error but txtnama.Text didn't show their 'nama'.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TppJU.png)

I think everyone will understand by looking the code. I can't explain much as my English isn't well enough.

Comment: You joined the two tables with an [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) (implicit). If `tabsen` can yield empty data you have to do a [right outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) (or a left outer join when switching the tables). If both can be empty you have to go with a [full outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp).

Comment: *empty data = no data

Comment: now its fixed.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... from tabsen join tsiswa on ...
```

This produces an [Inner Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on the two tables which will only provide results if both tables have matching data.

Use either [Right (Outer) Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp)

```
... from tabsen right join tsiswa on ...
```

Or [Left (Outer) Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
... from tsiswa left join tabsen on ...
```

Having said that, be aware that if `tabsen` does not contain matching rows **all** of its attributes are `NULL` values.
So you have to check that when assigning values from the datareader to the textboxes:

```
Dim id_absen = dr.Item("id_absen") 
txtid.Text = If(id_absen<> DBNull.Value, id_absen.ToString(), String.Empty)
...
```

Btw...I would recommend you set `Option Strict On` at the very top of your VB file. Will give you some compile errors but save you alot of mean bugs in the future.

Comment: thank you alex. i really need to deep-learn about mysql . my problem solved now